# AS3.0 Tween detecting where a tween stops

Tags: actionscript-3, detection, progress, tween

Would like to detect where a tween has stopped before finishing. The implementation of this can be when I alpha tween a MovieClip from 0 to 1 with a Mouse Roll_Over but I do not finish the tween and instead I Roll_Out the Mouse. The starting value of the reversed alpha tween is not 1 but an intermediate value between 0 and 1 depending on where och when the tween has stopped.

My question is to detect that value when the tween stopped progressing.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Come again? You can just check the value of any property you are tweening.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with just the alpha property. So your Roll_Out function would be:

```
function Roll_Out(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(e.currentTarget, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, e.currentTarget.alpha, 1, 1, true);
}
```

Or alternatively, if you're using TweenMax

```
function Roll_Out(e:MouseEvent):void{
    TweenMax.killTweenOf(e.currentTarget);
    TweenMax.to(e.currentTarget, 1, {alpha: 1});
}
```

Any property that you tween is accessible by the current object's value of that property. e.currentTarget is this instance refers to the DisplayObject you are hovering over.